# Exporting Video From Blender Video Editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I pasted the saved image frames from my blender cycles rendering into the blender video editor. How do I export the frames from the blender video editor into a video using cycles?

Answer (score 2):

After you placed your images and set their duration in the *Video Sequence Editor* (VSE), all you need to do is set up the video format (lower red rectangle in the image below) you need and render as an animation (upper red rectangle).

When there's content in the VSE, it overrides anything else you have in your scene and when you render, it will render out the content in the VSE, instead of using the rendering engine to render your scene.

[image: Example]

Comment: Will VSE override if sequencer isn't checked in the post processing panel of render properties?

Comment: As far as I know it will, it always takes precedent in my scenes and I've never changed this parameter.